# Connection string to ms-access database not correct in deployed PHP site

Tags: php, ms-access

I have successfully made a connection to my access database on my local computer but when I upload my config.php file which contains the connection string on my web server and when the insert command runs it displays a blank page without making entries to the database.

```
 $conn = new COM ("ADODB.Connection")
  or die("Cannot start ADO");
  $connStr = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=/onlineadmission.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=;";
  $conn->open($connStr);
```

It works well on my local computer but not when uploaded.
Where is the problem?

Comment: Provide valid DB credentials

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the selected driver (Microsoft JET OLEDB 4.0) is installed on the server?

Also put your code into an try-catch block to catch the [COM exceptions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/com.error-handling.php)

Comment: i did it.. no errors. but when i use firephp it says "500 Internal Server Error". i have tested the code on local machine i get the o/p properly